# Magento font_color phtml error no idea where to even start

Tags: magento, php

I keep getting the following error filling up my system log constantly.

```
2014-03-04T11:52:56+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: font_color  in /var/www/html/waxmanenergy.co.uk/magento/app/design/frontend/default/mt_gero/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 31
```

Im not sure whats wrong with it or how to go about fixing it.

This is whats in line 31 on the error path within the header.phtml file

```
$text_color = isset($_COOKIE['textColor']) ? $_COOKIE['textColor'] : $config['font_color'];
```

Anyone got any heads up to what could be the issue

Comment: $config['font_color'] is blank or not assigned check the $config array in your file.

Answer (score 0):

$config of yours do not have any index like 'font_color'.  Either $config is not an array of array without 'font_color' as its key.